Initial Condition Dependence of an SDE
Now consider the following SDE system:
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d}r_t&=-\kappa(r_t-\bar{r})\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\sqrt{v_t}\mathrm{d}B_{rt}\\
\mathrm{d}v_t&=-K(v_t-\bar{v})\mathrm{d}t+\sigma_v\sqrt{v_t}\mathrm{d}B_{vt}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathrm{d}B_{rt}\mathrm{d}B_{vt}=\rho\mathrm{d}t$. With initial condition $r_0$ and $v_0$. Now I want to prove that
$$\int_0^{T}r_t\mathrm{d}t$$
is increasing with respect to $r_0$ while other parameters remain the same. Here's my thought:
Suppose that $\hat{r}_0>r_0$. Then the process $\hat{r}_t$ will greater than $r_t$ almost surely. Since
$$\frac{\partial r_t}{\partial r_0}=1-\kappa\int_0^{t}\frac{\partial r_s}{\partial r_0}\mathrm{d}s\Rightarrow\frac{\partial r_t}{\partial r_0}=e^{-\kappa t}>0$$
Thus for any $\omega\in\Omega$ and any $t\in[0,T]$, we must have
$$\hat{r}_t(\omega)>r_t(\omega)$$
Thus for any $\omega$,
$$\int_0^{T}\hat{r}_t\mathrm{d}t\geq\int_0^{T}r_t\mathrm{d}t$$
Is it legitimate to do this? How can I refine this proof, being more rigorous? Is there any material that I can refer? Thanks!

I found Proposition 5.2.18 in 'Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus' by Karatzas and Shreve may help.
